# How can I select specific cell in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select a specific cell in this dataframe?, the index in this data frame is the Fishes column.

My expected output is: e.g
 > 35045.12 
 or anything in the production column. Thanks a lot!

```
Fishes                 | Month | Year | production
BF - Milkfish          |   3   | 2019 | 35045.12
BF - Tilapia           |   6   | 2019 | 68666.64
BF - Tiger prawn       |   9   | 2019 | 77064.91
BF - Mudcrab           |   12  | 2019 | 58163.4
BF - Endeavor prawn    |   3   | 2020 | 38108.49
BF - White shrimp      |   6   | 2020 | 67663.83
BF - Grouper           |   9   | 2020 | 71316.94
```

Comment: `df['production']['BF - Milkfish']` probably

Comment: @SuperStew I am getting an error. KeyError: 'BF - Milkfish'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(df.loc['BF - Milkfish', 'production'])
# or
print(df['production'].iloc[0])
```

```
35045.12
```

Comment: I need your first code but I get an error. KeyError: 'BF - Milkfish'

Comment: @love What's the result of `print(df.index)`?

Comment: Index(['BF - Milkfish ', 'BF - Tilapia', 'BF - Tiger prawn', 'BF - Mudcrab',
       'BF - Endeavor prawn ', 'BF - White shrimp ', 'BF - Grouper', name='Fishes')

Comment: I know my mistake BF - Milkfish has a space so that i get that error. Thankyousoomuch!!!!

Comment: booooo `loc` boooooo

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the answer you are looking for, this is simply another way if you wanted to add to your bag of tricks

```
df['production'].loc[df['Fishes'] == 'BF - Milkfish'].squeeze()
```

Comment: I am getting an error of. KeyError: 'Fishes'

Comment: Why did our convo get deleted?

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure...it was probably some higher ranking person thinking we should do this in chat or something